Changing output impedance of a logic gate to 50 ohm
I making a simple circuit to take 10 MHz output from a GPS module and calibrate a frequency counter with this 10 MHz signal. I have already found a circuit designed by radio amateur ZL2PD. Circuit uses 74HC14 Schmitt trigger inverters to buffer the signal. Please refer the circuit below. 10 MHz signal is coming out of PPS pin of GPS module and then signal is given to the Schmitt trigger inverters

In this circuit, the output of 4 Schmitt trigger inverter is combined and resistors connected in series with the output to make the output impedance close to 50 Ω. I cannot understand how the output impedance becomes 50 Ω just by connecting the resistors in series with output. Four 220 Ω resistor if connected in parallel, then it becomes close to 50 Ω, but in this circuit, the resistors are not parallel, instead, they are in series with output of each gate. How this makes impedance at output close to 50 Ω at RF out port J2?
Link to circuit
https://www.zl2pd.com/GPS_Freq_Ref.html

The buffer output impedance needs to be viewed looking into the output from J2. When viewed that way, the resistors are indeed in parallel. This assumes negligible impedance in the output drivers.

Are you sure they're not aiming at 75 ohms Rout? Or maybe 'somewhere between' 50 and 75 ohms, so it's reasonable in either system.

Not aiming for 75 ohm. As Amateur radio uses 50 ohm system most of the time

There are IBIS models available for this IC.  You can use them along with this answer of mine which shows how to get an estimate of the non-zero output impedance of each gate output: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/573907

You can imagine that each gate outputs effectively an identical signal, so the output is also four gates in parallel.
However, each logic gate already has an internal output impedance, maybe around 22 to 33 ohms, so in reality the 220 ohms is a bit on the high side, but adequate as usually the output impedance is not that important.

I have accepted this as answer, but all other answers are also pointing at the same conclusion. It could have been better to use little less than 220 ohms, but as circuit already built and tested, working fine.

About 20 years ago, I went through this for a couple of MIL projects that used a 1 pps signal defined in a Rockwell document.  Turns out, it is much more important that the far end of the coax cable be terminated in exactly 50 ohms, than having the driving point impedance be 50 ohms.
The reason for the 50 ohm source impedance is to minimize re-reflections of energy coming back up the cable from the receiver.  As with most things regarding noise and distortion, it is better to reduce such items at the point of their generation than somewhere else.  In your case. the smaller the reflections coming back from the receiver to the source, the smaller the re-reflections produced by source impedance mismatch.  It is these re-reflections getting back to the receiver that introduce phase (timing) distortion into the waveform.
If the receiver terminates the cable perfectly, there are no reflections.  In this case, the driving point impedance can be anything.  In the real world, the receiver can be terminated in something very close to perfect, such as 49.9 ohms, but there will be a reactive component caused by circuit capacitances, stray inductance, etc.  Often, this is the source of reflections back up the cable.  If the receiver input is well-designed and fabricated, these reflections are so small that they will induce very little phase distortion into the timing waveform.
This can be tested by observing the waveform at the receiver both while driving the cable with the output resistors in the circuit and with the cable connected directly to the IC outputs.
As in other answers, a better value for your output resistors is 150 ohms.
BTW, in my project I went with a true 50 ohm driver, a switched current source with a 49.9 ohm resistor to GND.  In this way I could deliver a 3.5 V pulse, properly source terminated, with only a 5 V rail.
Update:
Since you are using the 1 pps merely as a gate signal to a frequency counter, it is not all that important that there be zero phase distortion in the signal.  All that matters is that whatever distortions there are are constant, giving a consistent signal to the frequency counter.

See Update. . . .

The circuit with 220Ω resistors assumes that the gate output impedance is zero - that the gates are voltage sources. To get their output impedance above zero, a series resistor has to be added. The gates are identical so their outputs are at the same potential at all times. So connecting resistors to different gates is no different than connecting them to the same gate in parallel as you’d expect.
Now, in practice the logic family specifications determine typical output impedance, and it is above zero.
Here the use of several gates benefits us. Imagine that the gates have say 22Ω output impedance. That’s only a 10% error relative to the 220Ω series resistor.
Now say we used just one gate with a 50Ω series resistor. The 22Ω output impedance adds almost 50% more impedance on top of 50Ω of our resistor.
So that’s why multiple gates are used and paralleled. The circuit is much less sensitive to the output impedance of each individual gage. That output impedance varies due to random semiconductor process parameter spread, and with temperature too.
Finally, note that four 220Ω resistors in parallel have 55Ω combined resistance. Why not use 200Ω instead? Because 220Ω is an E-series value available in 5% and better tolerances. The circuit is not meant to provide a very accurate 50Ω output impedance. If it did, the resistors would be less than 200Ω anyway, due to non-zero gate output impedance.
In practice if you wanted to tune such a circuit to perform best with a
50Ω cable, you’d look at the load termination signal, and adjust the resistor values until the signal looked best, ie. with least artifacts due to reflections. In this clock-distribution scenario, this is not a big concern, especially not in hobbyist applications.

I imagine the use of four gates in parallel is also because one 74-series gate typically can't drive a 100Ω load. Depending on the logic family, you could need anywhere from two to impractically-many gates. 74LVC is pretty good for this, 74AUP is pretty bad.

@Hearth Yep, that too :)

Here we have four voltage sources, \$V_1\$ to \$V_4\$ each sourcing/sinking current via an independent 220Ω resistor, to/from a potential set by another voltage source \$V_0\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The current sourced by each voltage source is (by Ohm's law):
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1 &= \frac{V_1-V_0}{R_1} \\ \\
I_2 &= \frac{V_2-V_0}{R_2} \\ \\
I_3 &= \frac{V_3-V_0}{R_3} \\ \\
I_4 &= \frac{V_4-V_0}{R_4} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
By Kirchhoff's Current Law, current \$I_0\$ is the sum of all those individual contributions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_0 = \frac{V_1-V_0}{R_1} + \frac{V_2-V_0}{R_2} + \frac{V_3-V_0}{R_3} + \frac{V_4-V_0}{R_4} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
When these voltage sources are all identical, as would be the case for your four inverters, and all the resistances are identical as is the case also, then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V &= V_1 = V_2 = V_3 = V_4 \\ \\
R &= R_1 = R_2 = R_3 = R_4 \\ \\
I_0 &= \frac{V-V_0}{R} + \frac{V-V_0}{R} + \frac{V-V_0}{R} + \frac{V-V_0}{R} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{R}\left[ (V-V_0) + (V-V_0) + (V-V_0) + (V-V_0) \right] \\ \\
&= \frac{4}{R}(V-V_0) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Rearrange that a little, to obtain the ratio of potential difference to current (otherwise known as "resistance"):
$$ \frac{R}{4} = \frac{V-V_0}{I_0} $$
In plain English this is saying that the potential difference \$V-V_0\$ across a single resistance \$\frac{R}{4}\$ will produce the same current \$I_0\$.
There's no functional or behavioural difference between the original 4-source and 4-resistor setup, and a single voltage source \$V\$ with single resistance \$R_0=\frac{R}{4}\$:

simulate this circuit

To be pedantic, the inverter gates have a few ohms of output resistance, which will compound with the 220Ω resistances at the individual outputs, meaning that the total equivalent source impedance will be higher than the 55Ω shown above.
To get closer to the 50Ω desired, employ resistances slightly under 200Ω. If I represent the inverter output impedances as the 5Ω resistors here, and replace the 220Ω devices with 195Ω:

simulate this circuit
If the output resistance of those gates are indeed 5Ω (which could be ascertained experimentally), then this arrangement would provide an equivalent total output impedance \$R\$:
$$ R = \frac{5\Omega + 195\Omega}{4} = 50\Omega $$
Since this is a digital signal, I don't think a few ohms of difference between the transmission line's characteristic impedance and the output impedance of the source will have any serious consequences, so 220Ω will be fine too, for a 50Ω coaxial transmission line.


I cannot understand how the output impedance becomes 50 Ω just by connecting the resistors in series with output. Four 220 Ω resistor if connected in parallel, then it becomes close to 50 Ω, but in this circuit, the resistors are not parallel, instead, they are in series with output of each gate.

Output impedance is the ratio between a small change in the output voltage and the corresponding small change in the output current. For example, if changing the output current by \$1 \ \mathrm{mA}\$ causes the output voltage to change by \$50 \ \mathrm{mV}\$ in the usual direction, then the output impedance is \$50 \ \Omega\$.
In the case of your circuit, let's consider what would happen if we changed the output voltage by \$220 \ \mathrm{mV}\$. That would cause the voltage across each of the output resistors to change by \$220 \ \mathrm{mV}\$ as well. This will cause the current through each resistor to change by \$1 \ \mathrm{mA}\$, meaning that the total current will change by \$4 \ \mathrm{mA}\$. The output impedance is defined as the ratio between these two changes, which is
$$\frac{220 \ \mathrm{mV}}{4 \ \mathrm{mA}} = 55 \ \Omega.$$
Sure enough, this is close to \$50 \ \Omega\$.
